# fasm and glut simple example with .inc file

Tags: glut, fasm

I need a simple example created with fasm and using glut lib.
I search on internet but seam nobody have a correct *glut.inc* file.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLUT .inc file can be found [here](https://board.flatassembler.net/~flatasse/subdomains/board/topic.php?p=1601).

Is there a particular reason you want to use glut? There is an opengl/glu example in the fasm package for windows... Maybe that would be more useful?

Comment: 1.The example for fasm forum is not functional... somthing about "missing end directive" ... maybe is something simple but will take time .  2.I need glut because I want make a crossplatform interface windows - linux